# First rule of a "Well-Formed XML Document"

Tags: xml, w3c

This is the first rule of the [XML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-well-formed).

> `[1] document ::= ( prolog element Misc* ) - ( Char* RestrictedChar Char* )`

I understand the first part: a `document` contains a `prolog`, an `element` and optional `Misc`-items.

But I do not understand the part starting with the hyphen. What does this mean? Can anybody give an example for a document containing such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Extended Backus-Naur Form](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-notation),

```
A - B
```

matches any string that matches `A` but does not match `B`.

Therefore, an XML document,

> `[1] document ::= ( prolog element Misc* ) - ( Char* RestrictedChar Char* )`

must match the first part `( prolog element Misc* )` without matching the second part `( Char* RestrictedChar Char* )` or, in short...

**An XML `document` must not include any restricted characters.**

Comment: This is a spooky notation, I have never seen before. I think it will be much better to define A in a way, that B is not allowed in the first place, instead of allowing B in order to reject it later on.